# Convergence - $\log(2)$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence

Denote
$$
t(n) := \frac{|\{ \sigma \in S_n \mid \sigma \text{ has a cycle of length > $\frac n 2$} \}|}{|S_n|}
$$
Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} t(n) = \log 2$. Can someone help ? I already know that this is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k > \frac n 2}^n \frac 1 k = \log 2
$$

Comment: This problem was discussed by several contributors at this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259351/permutations-with-a-cycle-fracn2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a picture:

$$\int_{n+1}^{2n+1}\frac{dx}x\le H_{2n}-H_n\le\frac1{n+1}+\int_n^{2n}\frac{dx}x\;,$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Hi, do you know some source which gives a deeper insight of this result by generating functions ?

Comment: @André: Not really. The closest is [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/260320/12042) by Marko Riedel to an earlier question.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=\frac n2}^{n}\frac1k=\frac1n\sum_{k=\frac n2}^{n}\frac1{\frac kn}$$ A Riemann sum can be converted to an integral if n tends to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic problem of mathematicians trying to find their names in boxes.

Solution can be found online, here for example http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/solutions.pdf (page 3)